# Simultaneous jobs that read from the same file lead to one interrupting the other

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I have made a program to run an `.exe` file on scheduled times using a `Windows service`. Each run of the `.exe` file does the following:

1. Inserts a record in the database with the status `"Running"`
2. Reads from a source file
3. Inserts information inside the file into another table (recipients information)
4. Sets the status of the record in step 1 to `"Run"`

So when the status is "Run", we know that the process has completed.

Almost under all scenarios, everything is working fine *except* when we have two jobs who (1) have the same schedule (run the above `.exe` file every minute) and (2) read from the same file.

The program acts quite strange in such case. And again this does not happen all the time. But what happens is that if two versions of the `.exe` file are running simultaneously (say process `A` and `B` that are basically the same `.exe` file), even though I know the entire process takes less than a second, process `A` remains in the `"Running"` state and its work is left undone while process `B` steals the file information and inserts them under its own name!

This is the relevant part in my quartz.config:

```
# Quartz Config

quartz.threadPool.type = Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz
quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
#quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = Normal

# Settings for using Quartz as a windows service
quartz.scheduler.exporter.type = Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz
quartz.scheduler.exporter.port = 555
quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName = Postbag
quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType = tcp
quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName = httpQuartz

# SQLite settings
quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default
quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz
quartz.dataSource.default.provider = SQLite-10
quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString = Data Source=.\jobs.db;Version=3
```

My service says both `A` and `B` are triggered successfully. Otherwise there will be no record in the database with `"Running"` status.

I don't know how this happens. If this was something that happened every time, it would have been much easier to detect. But this starts to happen after 20 or sometimes 50 runs of both processes. I seriously have run out of ideas on this. Does anyone have a clue or have faced the same problem?

Comment: Do you catch and log exceptions?

Comment: If you don't mind a slight processing delay you could always add a mutex to the program so that multiple instances can't simultaneously access the database, but pause until the other process has finished (see [link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Mutex) )

Comment: @hatchet I have done my best to catch and log everything. What I suspect is that in my case the second process actually terminates the first one! So no logging is done in this case.

Comment: @JamesS I'm afraid I have announced the parallel job run as one of the advantages of my program. So locking tables would undermine that concept.

Comment: @Pedram - Where I was headed with the exception question was whether you've ruled out the possibility that the one whose last recorded state was "Running" threw an uncaught exception when it tried to open the file the other process already had open. I don't think one process terminates the other. One of them just self destructs with an uncaught exception.

Comment: @hatchet it sucks that I cannot run this scenario in debug mode! the service only logs whether the job is "about to trigger" or "triggered". I will not know if one `.exe` file has crashed due to an uncaught exception or not.

Comment: If the programs are your programs, there are places where you can put a global error handler to catch otherwise uncaught exceptions.

Comment: No idea if this will solve it or not - but you could try putting the database in [WAL](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) (write ahead log) mode

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the `.exe` file.  If it isn't your code, and doesn't support running multiple instances in parallel, you're probably stuck - though perhaps running one simultaneous instance per source file would be adequate?

Comment: @HarryJohnston you have a point there. and actually it is quite a rare scenario that two processes read from the same file at the same time. I'll give it some more reflection and if it still did not work we're going to prevent two processes reading from the same file.